# If $\int_0^t f(s) \, \mathrm d s = 0$ for a.e. $t \in (0, 1)$, then $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces, alternative-proof

In solving exercise 5.30.4 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, I have come across below lemma

> Let $f \in L^1(0, 1)$ such that $\int_0^t f(s) \, \mathrm d s = 0$ for a.e. $t \in (0, 1)$. Then $f=0$ a.e.

1. Could you have a check on my attempt?
2. Is there another approach that sidesteps Lebesgue’s differentiation theorem?

---

By dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$
\int_0^t f(s) \, \mathrm d s = \lim_{h \to t} \int_0^h f(s) \, \mathrm d s
\quad \forall t \in (0, 1).
$$

It follows that $\int_0^t f(s) \, \mathrm d s = 0$ for all $t \in (0, 1)$.

> [Lebesgue’s differentiation theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539671/a-proof-of-lebesgue-s-differentiation-theorem) Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f \in L_1(\Omega)$. Then for a.e. $x \in \Omega$, we have
> $$
> f(x) = \lim _{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|} \int_{B(x, r)} f(y) \mathrm d y.
> $$
> Here $B(x, r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$, and $|E|$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $E \subset \mathbb R^n$.

For any $x\in (0, 1)$ and $r>0$ such that $B(x, r) \subset (0, 1)$, we have
$$
\int_{B(x, r)} f(y) \mathrm d y = \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(y) \mathrm d y = \int_0^{x+r} f(y) \mathrm d y - \int_0^{x-r} f(y) \mathrm d y = 0.
$$

The claim then follows from Lebesgue’s differentiation theorem.

Comment: This is a FAQ but since you are asking for a proof-verification, it cannot be considered as a (multi!)duplicate. + (after reading) Same commentS as FShrike's below.

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me. There should be more elementary ways of doing it

Comment: A [more elementary solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385753).